# what to do if kikid does not contains userid in firebase database?

Tags: android, database, firebase

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersdRef = rootRef.child("users");
    Query searchQuery = usersdRef.orderByChild("submission_time").limitToFirst(50);
    searchQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String kikid = ds.child("kikId").getValue(String.class);
                if (kikid.contains(userId)) {
                    // your username is already in the list
                    // Toast message of useId is already in the list
                }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This code will search all users `kikid` value, if `kikid` value contains `userid`(`edittext` value), then there will be toast message like user is exist, but What to do if `kikid` does not contains `userid`? where to write that code?

Comment: Add the else part of the statement.

Comment: else won't work. because for the first user, if Kikid does not contains usreid, it will do else fuction.

Comment: i want to check even if  a single users kikid doesnot contains userid, then go to else